# Disable erroneous file type detection by extension on ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I am trying to transcode mjpeg files with `ffmpeg` and it is incorrectly detecting settings. If the file has no extension, or an unknown extension, ffmpeg will correctly detect mjpeg format and will read any number of frames there happen to be.

What doesn't work is when the file has `.jpg` extension. This causes ffmpeg to only read one frame from the file and disregard any additional frames.

Is there any way to tell ffmpeg to stop guessing based on the file extension, or at least actually use the mjpeg module and not just read one frame?

I know about `-f image2pipe -i -` but that would require jumping through other hoops to pipe the file to the command and not just give the filename to the process since I'm executing it from another process without the shell.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you specify `mjpeg` input format before the input?  (`-f mjpeg -i image.jpg`)

Comment: @bertieb It does. Thought I tried that also, but I guess I only used mjpeg as codec, not format specifier. Please add it as an answer

Comment: Done!  I've had similar experiences with `ffmpeg`: "Try this... try that... try the other... Okay, that suggestion. Wait, that *worked*? I could swear it didn't 5 minutes ago..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How do I tell `ffmpeg` to use the format **I** want?

*(and not the one it **thinks** it should use)*

`ffmpeg` is picky about the position of its arguments. It sounds like you want to force it to use `mjpeg` as an input format, which means the `-f` needs to come *before* the `-i` argument. For example:

```
$ ffmpeg -f mjpeg -i mjpeg_image.jpg <other_options> output
```

You can also get a listing of supported formats by invoking `ffmpeg -formats`; where **`D`** indicates decoding (input) ability, and **`E`** indicates encoding (output) ability.

Comment: The error I had was that I only tried to use mjpeg as *codec* with `-i image2 -c:v mjpeg` and didn't realize that I can also use mjpeg as the *format* with `-f mjpeg`. So this fixed my problem perfectly.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yup- sounds like an input-versus-output bit, I tacked on a little bit at the end about that but could possibly expand on it further.